# Prove that $\dim(V)$ is even

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

> Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space. Let $A_1,A_2: V\rightarrow V$ be commuting linear operators such that $A_1+A_2=-I$ where $I$ is the identity operator. Also $A_1,A_2$ have no negative eigenvalues. Prove that $\dim(V)$ is even.

How to approach this problem?

Comment: first of all $A_1,A_2$ are injective and thus bijective. That's because if there exists  $x\neq 0$ such that $A_1x=0$ then $A_2x=-x$ and thus $A_2$ has a negative eigenvalue. Can you keep from here?

Comment: @draks... : How can you assume both to be diagonal?

Comment: I can tell it holds for $V$ = $\mathbb{R}$. This is not very groundbreaking, though.. :)

Comment: @draks... : By eigenbasis, do you mean a basis consisting of eigen-vectors? Why should either of them have such a basis? You are not given that they are normal.

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan yes you're right...I'll remove my comments!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Updated)

The assumption that $A_1$ and $A_2$ commute is superfluous. This already follows from $A_1+A_2=-I$.

It is tacitly assumed that the ground field is ${\mathbb R}$; for otherwise $A_1=[i]$, $A_2=[-1-i]$ would be a counterexample.

Now for the hint: Show that $A_1$ and $A_2$ can have no real eigenvalues at all, and think about the degree of the characteristic polynomial: it has to be even.

Comment: let $A_1v_1=\lambda_1v_1;A_2v_2=\lambda_2v_2;\lambda_2,\lambda_1\in \mathbb R$

Comment: then $A_1v_1+A_2v_1=-v_1\implies A_2v_1=-v_1-\lambda _1v_1$ hence $A_2$ has $-(1+\lambda _1)$ as its eigen value which is $<0$ and hence contradiction

Comment: Is this correct?How to proceed from here?

Comment: @learnmore to finish the proof, note that any polynomial $P\in \mathbb R[X]$ **with odd degree** has at least one real root.

Comment: @LeGrandDODOM since $\lambda >0$ and so $-(\lambda+1)$ is negative  hence a linear operator has  a negative value which is against the hypo I guess

Comment: @learnmore you're right. What confused me is that you did not mention that $\lambda_1$ is $\geq 0$ (the case $\lambda_1<0$ is dismissed by the hypothesis that $A_1$ must have non-negative eigenvalues).

Answer (score -1):

$A_1 + A_2 = -I$ => $A_2 = -I - A_1$

$ A_1A_2 - A_2A_1 = A_1(-I-A_1) - (-I-A_1)A_1 = 0 $

So for every $A_1$ there is an $A_2$ to commute with.

If $\lambda > 0$ is an eigenvalue of $A_1$ and s is eigenvector:

$A_2s = (-I-A_1)s = -(1+\lambda)s $
So if $A_1$ has only positive eignevalues, $A_2$ has only negative ones.

Comment: Is this an answer??Why is dim V even ?Cant find that

Comment: @learnmore I'm having trouble seeing the connection too.

Comment: I am afraid you may get some negative votes in this process @err513

Comment: learnmore:
It's a hint to approach the problem. If you need it, I'll comment the whole solution. 
But I think your question lacks some important information. Are $A_1$ and $A_2$ real or complex matrices?